# Creating a copy of an Assign to feild in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: azure-devops

I am customizing a bug template in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online), and I would like to add a new field called Required Information. but I would like it to be a drop down of the users that I can assign a TFS task to.

So I want a copy of the assign to dropdown.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily in on-premise TFS by modifying the process template. In VS Team Services, although you **can** customize work items, you **cannot** modify the process template directly.

Using identity (e.g. a user list) or custom pick-lists are not yet supported. The work to support those features is on-going and is targeted for the first half of 2016, per [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is nice.